# Fillin part of an image with a color in UWP (C#)

Tags: c#, bitmap, uwp, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to create a coloring book with blank pictures , i want to be able to fill a section of an image with a color but i can't figure out how to do so within UWP (C#/XAML)

[Example of what im trying to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NUqBR.png)

Comment: Could you post the code?

Comment: I don't know where to begin as Bitmap is not used in UWP

Comment: Please share us some code as Sean request, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to break the pictures up into different images.  Then you can fill in each one's foreground with a color. This should get you started.

XAML View:

```
<Grid>
    <BitmapIcon Name="PokeTail" UriSource="/Assets/Graphics/PokemonTail.png" Foreground="{Binding PokemonTailColor}" Tapped="PokeTail_Tapped" RightTapped="PokeTail_RightTapped"  />
    <BitmapIcon Name="PokeHead" UriSource="/Assets/Graphics/PokemonHead.png" Foreground="{Binding PokemonHeadColor}" Tapped="PokeHead_Tapped" RightTapped="PokeHead_RightTapped" />
    <Image Name="PokeOutline" Source="/Assets/Graphics/PokemonOutline.png"/>
</Grid>
```

C# Code Behind:

```
    private void PokeHead_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PokeHead.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Yellow);
    }

    private void PokeHead_RightTapped(object sender, RightTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PokeHead.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
    }

    private void PokeTail_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PokeTail.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Wheat);
    }

    private void PokeTail_RightTapped(object sender, RightTappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        PokeHead.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent);
    }
```

Comment: Will that not change the color of the whole section?

Comment: See the updated answer. Make a separate image file with the outline and leave the parts you want colored transparent.  Layer that on top of the rest.

Comment: Its working 50% but when i tap it colors the outline of the section of the image tapped, any ideas?

Comment: Did you see the updated answer?  Did you create an outline-only copy of the image?

Comment: Yes i Did, I made a full outline of the image, and seperated the images , here is whats happening now [link](https://i.gyazo.com/566e8cca66376946a6f022a3fbf1785a.png)